# INCLUDETEXT Select Specific Node Via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, ms-word

I am trying to use `INCLUDETEXT` with `xml` to populate a `field` in a Word document.

I want to grab a specific node based on an `Xpath` query that selects the node based on the value of a child node value.

For example, for the below xml:

```
<a:events xmlns:a="http://a.foo.org/">  
  <a:event> 
    <a:title>Number 1</a:title>  
    <a:status>Draft</a:status>  
    <a:description/> 
  </a:event>  
  <a:event> 
    <a:title>Number 2</a:title>  
    <a:status>Live</a:status>  
    <a:description/> 
  </a:event>  
</a:events>
```

the XPath query `a:events/a:event[a:status='Live']/a:title` should grab the element node `<a:title>Number 2</a:title>`.  I have confirmed this to work.

However, in Word, the below `INCLUDETEXT` does not work.

```
{ INCLUDETEXT  "foo.xml" \n xmlns:a=\"https://a.foo.org\" \x a:events/a:event[a:status='Live']/a:title \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Nothing is displayed in the `INCLUDETEXT` `field`.  I can get other basic `XPath` queries to work, including the `[]` selector, but this is not robust enough for my needs.

Is this type of `XPath` supported?  I have searched online for an answer, but this feature does not appear to be documented that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I would answer this in case anyone else is stuck with this.

The trick ended up being to place the `XPath` expression in quotes:

```
{ INCLUDETEXT  "foo.xml" \n xmlns:a=\"https://a.foo.org\" \x "a:events/a:event[a:status='Live']/a:title" \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Once placed in quotes, all worked as expected.